# React How to prevent useEffect execution when input is blank?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useEffect for username field to check if the typed username by user already exists in the database

```
const[username,setUsername]=useState('');


useEffect(()={
 // Logic here to fetch and check if typed username already exists
},[username]);
```

I want to execute this useEffect only when username is non-blank. It renders this useeffect on initial page render, which I do not want to happen.

useRef is preventing only on initial render, but every time this username field is blank from non-blank, this should not execute.

Any help on this, please?

Comment: Does this work? Inside the useEffect, `if(!username) return; // followed by logic to fetch`

Comment: Yes. It should work. But i thought of preventing the execution of useeffect itself. But i can also implement this method. I did not think of it.

Comment: you have to use `onChange()` method instead of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if condition

```
useEffect(()={
   if(usename){
     // Logic here to  
   }
},[username]);
```

Comment: Yes. I did implement this way.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

```
const[username,setUsername]=useState('');


useEffect(()={
 // Logic here to fetch and check if typed username already exists
},[username]);

const changeHandler = (event) => {
    const username = event.target.value;
    if(username === '') return;
    setUsername(username);
}


<input onChange={()=>changeHandler(event)}/>
```

Comment: This way triggers for each and every typed letter. I am worried about how much it will impact the performance as an Appsync query has to be called each time when username is typed.

Comment: have you tried onBlur? it will trigger the function only when focus is lost.